# NestJS: Make a dynamic module talk to a mongoose collection name passed as parameter

Tags: typescript, mongoose, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm using mongoose, and I was wondering if it's possible to have a module that export a Service, but the service would talk with a different database and/or collection depending on the configuration.

I've tried like this, but when I import EventStoreModule with same uri but different collection names, event are kept in the same collection. What I'm doing wrong? I don't even know if it's possible because MongooseEventStore follows Singleton Pattern I imagine.

```
@Module({})
export class EventStoreModule {
  static register({
    uri,
    collection_name,
    options,
  }: EventStoreModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: EventStoreModule,
      imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot(uri, options),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([
          {
            name: Event.name,
            schema: EventSchema,
            collection: collection_name,
          },
        ]),
      ],
      providers: [MongooseEventStore],
      exports: [MongooseEventStore],
    };
  }
}
```

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MongooseEventStore
  implements IEventPublisher<BaseEvent>, IMessageSource
{
  private subject$: Subject<IEvent>;
  private eventMapper: Record<string, (data: QoalaEventDocument) => BaseEvent>;

  constructor(
    @InjectModel(QoalaEvent.name)
    private readonly eventModel: Model<QoalaEventDocument>,
  ) {}
}
```